# How to count number of solution for this problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Find some natural number which the sum of their inverse is equal to 0.601

I find that for such a problems I should look for factor of 1000 which
is the set  {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 25, 40, 50, 100, 125, 200, 250,
500, 1000} so I should look for factors that their sum became 601
which is for this problem the solutions is {1+100+500=601} and
{250+200+125+25+1=601} now if I divide 1000 on these sets, those
natural number bacame 1000/500,1000/100, 1000/1 so the natural number
for this set is 2, 10, 1000 and for the other set is 1000/250, 1000/200, 1000/125, 1000/25, 1000/1 therefor the natural number for this set is 4, 5, 8, 40 & 1000.

Now if the number 0.601 change or suppose generalize like 0.abc...z
(it has n decimals) then I should find 10^n factors and look for the
sum of factors which is equal to abc.....z now this number become so
big and so its factors now how could I count the solutions.

Comment: Could you phrase the question better? Because from your question it seems like I were to pick only one natural number, then what sum are you talking about? Are you talking about the sum of the inverse of the factors? Or the inverse of the sum of the factors? Or otherwise?

Comment: suppose 0.601 is given and we want to find those natural number first we multiply this number by 1000 so the number become 601 now we find factors of 1000 which is {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 25, 40, 50, 100, 125, 200, 250, 500, 1000} now in order to find the natural numbers I should find factors of 1000 that their sum is equal to 601 like {1+100+500} after that by dividing 1000 by these factors I find the natural numbers (for first set the natural number is {1000, 2, 10} & sum of their inverse is equal to 0.601) how can I count these set of factors?